# Stuck in Odin Mode | Installing Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android

Trying to install Ubuntu Touch on my Samsung Galaxy S5.

I've been using [this](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/) guide (the standard one), and things worked smoothly up until

`$ adb reboot bootloader`

Where I should have been on the screen with the "Android robot lying on its back with its front panel open", I got ODIN MODE. Neither `adb` or `fastboot` connected to the device after that, and the only way to get off the screen was to pull the battery.

I've tried factory resetting the phone via the phone, and the problem didn't fix. I now get another screen that look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kyrq.jpg). This screen replaces what I would get if I tried to get to the factory reset screen.

Is there a way to install Ubuntu Touch through Odin mode, or is there a way to get around it?

Comment: I figured out most of my problem. For starters, the combination I was doing where I expected to get the recovery mode was wrong.

I was pressing VolDown + Home + Power when I needed to press VolUp + Home + Power.

From here, I will try to use this screen to install Ubuntu Touch. Will update.

Comment: I have an old Galaxy S5, and I am interested in if this works.  Looking forward to your updates.  Edit your question when you update.